# wpf - add setter from code

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to add button from code and add triggers and setters to it. I wolud like to create button like this:

```
<Button Height="25" Width="100" Name="TestColorButton" Margin="10, 5, 0, 0">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=ColorTextBox}"></TextBlock>
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Fill, ElementName=NormalRectangle}"/>
                <Setter Property="Template"> <!-- I need this setter -->
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    </Border>
                         </ControlTemplate>
                     </Setter.Value>
                 </Setter>
             <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Fill, ElementName=MouseOverRectangle}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Fill, ElementName=ClickRectangle}"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
       </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

I found how to do everything except one setter. I checked it by comment. I tried many times and I got only something like this:

```
ContentPresenter contentPresenter = new ContentPresenter
        {
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
        };

        Border border = new Border();
        var binding = new Binding("Background");
        binding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.Self);
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(border, BackgroundProperty, binding);
        border.Child = contentPresenter;

        ControlTemplate controlTemplate = new ControlTemplate(typeof (Button));
        Setter templateSetter = new Setter(TemplateProperty, controlTemplate);

        style.Setters.Add(templateSetter);
```

I know it can not work, but I don't know how to do it differently.

Comment: @Franck sorry, it is. creating UI elements in procedural code in WPF is not only bad practice, but cumbersome and complicated. The OP already has the needed XAML, he just needs to let go the procedural mentality and understand the WPF mentality. I'm not sure how my comment is "not constructive".

Comment: it sound agressive and imperative to cancel all he is doing. BUT you are right as it should stay XAML but sometime you have no choice like when your interface is fully customizable and saved in database and saving as XAML snippet not useful when the same properties are used on other language.

Comment: I know it is not a good practice, but is there another way to allow user to add buttons from GUI? And I don't know how many buttons user will add.

Comment: Read about [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and learn how databinding works. One way you could do what you are looking for is binding a Collection object to a control that support collections such as listbox,itemcontrol or even combobox and apply the template you made to it's item and it will create 1 button per item in the collection. In WPF you can't jump on the language like you may have done with winforms. It's a much more sensible GUI design.

Comment: I'll do it for sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template can be added by code easily. here an example with a label.

```
// create the label with some context
var lbl = new Label() { DataContext = new ImageData(imagePath) };

// control template i want to put on the label
ControlTemplate labelLayout = new ControlTemplate();

// will be my main container that will be by template later on
FrameworkElementFactory grdContainer = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
grdContainer.Name = "myContainer";

// another element but ill put it in the grid (template)
FrameworkElementFactory myImage = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));

// some bindings and setters
myImage.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("ImagePath"));
myImage.SetValue(Image.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
myImage.SetValue(Image.HeightProperty, height);
myImage.SetValue(Image.WidthProperty, double.NaN);
myImage.SetValue(Image.SnapsToDevicePixelsProperty, true);

// add the image to the grid
grdContainer.AppendChild(myImage);

// set the visual layout of the template to be the grid (main container)
labelLayout.VisualTree = grdContainer;

// set the template (line you are looking for mostly)
lbl.Template = labelLayout;
```

Comment: I am afraid, I'm new in wpf and I don't know how to translate it for my needs. When I try it, my other setters stopped their work and button looks like normal button, not in my style with my triggers. I create the other setters with `new Setter(property, value)` and then I add it to style and then i add style to my button.

Comment: This code above may seems to you easier to understand coming from winforms environment and it works but it is much easier to handle in XAML than code behind.